# Could the "java" tag be enhanced to prompt the user for stacktraces?

Tags: feature-request

It is very common for Java questions to include troublesome code and the words "Doesn't work" or "throws an exception" but not the stack trace which tells the experienced programmer a great deal about what is actually wrong.  (This includes the asker making incorrect deductions about what is the problem).

Could the java-tag have extra fairy dust to prompt the user to include the appropriate stack trace(s)? Perhaps even a checkbox to say "Yes, I have included ..."?

Perhaps the C# folks would like the same feature :)

Comment: If you downvote this because I am ignorant or worse, please leave a comment on why.  I'd like to learn.

Comment: Many Java questions should not have attached stack traces. That includes wrong answer questions, failure to compile, and "Is there any way to...". How do you propose to distinguish those questions from questions for which a stack trace would be available and useful?

Comment: All debugging-questions should contain the neccessary info to diagnose the error, not only for java (which might not mean stack-traces at all). But not all programming questions by a long shot (though probably most bad ones which aren't do my work for me now) are debugging-questions.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Downvotes on Meta mean disagreement. It's entirely possible that people don't like your `feature-request`.

Comment: Or just direct them to [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: I agree that this might be painful for all Java questions, but what about for those which mention the word exception?

Answer (score 5):

It's true that there are a lot of novice question that are marked "Java" or "C#", but those tags are so broad that (IMO) this feature would be overly invasive.  Exceptions/compiler errors with stack traces are only one possible problem for potential questions.

As much as I'd like to prevent "I have an error, but I didn't include it" questions, I don't want to have to dismiss "include" your stack trace every time I have a Java/C# question, especially if my question doesn't have a stack trace.